# How to edit moodle core files with plugins?

Tags: php, moodle

I was trying to make some features inside my version of Moodle but that requires to alter or edit the core files or add new functions to the core files and for sure if I tried to upgrade my version all edits will be gone so I was trying to create a plugin for this edits but couldn't find any how to do it .. and most of the documents for older version .. so my question now is how to modify core files with a plugin?

Thanks

Comment: Moodle is modulized, so you can create plugins for specific needs. Pleas tell us what kind of core functions you want to overwrite and why.

Answer (score 0):

> how to modify core files with a plugin

You cannot do it directly, but you may use the [CustomScripts](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/customscripts) functionality to substitute executable files with your own